# How can I solve 'Functions are not valid as a React child.' error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native

Here is the function I'm calling below:

```
const timerDisplay = () => {
        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
          return (
            <Text>{numbers[i]}</Text>
          )
        }
 }
```

Calling:

```
<View style={styles.timerTop}>
        <Text style={styles.textTopBot}>{timerDisplay}</Text>
      </View>
```

So, when I refresh the project it gets me the 'Functions are not valid as a React child'. How can I solve this?

Comment: You did not call the function

Comment: Also there's generally no point to a `for` loop if you return on the first iteration.

Comment: I would say that timerDisplay, does not do what you expect it to do.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this keyword

```
{timerDisplay} --> {this.timerDisplay}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<View style={styles.timerTop}>
    <View style={styles.textTopBot}>
      {numbers.map((number) => <Text>{number}</Text>)}
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Can you please add some explaination to your code? [Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using class component.

//the function

```
timerDisplay = () => {
            for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
              return (
                <Text>{numbers[i]}</Text>
              )
            }
     }
```

//call the function

```
<View style={styles.timerTop}>
  <Text style={styles.textTopBot}>{this.timerDisplay}</Text>
</View>
```